# Disabling Case sensitivity for my keyword search

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a filter by text search in my wpf application. However when I do a string comparison to check if it contains a buzzword like, oh say "error", I want it to update/refresh my datagrid with all entries that have the Error keyword; regardless if I typed Error, or error, or eRRor in my search box.

Here is my code:

```
public class Foo 
{
  private void GetFilteredResults(MessageDetails detail, FilterEventArgs e)
  {
    foreach (MessageValue value in detail.MessageValue)
    {
       if (value.Value.Contains(txtFilterValue.Text))
       {
           //Returns true...
       }
    }
    //Otherwise false
  }
}
```

The **Messagedetails** is a container class and holds all of the datagrid row values.

The **MessageValue** is a struct that holds the actual message value in an ***ObservableCollection***

Finally, the **txtFilterValue** is the control name of the *textbox* I am using to for my word filter

What I want to do is setup something to where I remove case sensitivity in order to cache all entries that match my keyword, regardless of how I type it. How would I go about that?

Comment: `txtFilterValue.Text.ToUpper()` or `txtFilterValue.Text.ToLower()` to convert the string to only uppercase or lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there is a boolean property `CaseSensitive` identifying the *search mode*. Then you can use `string.IndexOf` to solve this by setting the `StringComparison` correctly:

```
StringComparison comparison = CaseSensitive ?
    StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
if (value.Value.IndexOf(txtFilterValue.Text, comparison) >= 0)
{
    //Returns true...
}
```

The whole query can be simply written with LINQ like

```
private void GetFilteredResults(MessageDetails detail, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    bool comparison = CaseSensitive ?
        StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
    return detail.MessageValue.Any(v => v.Value.IndexOf(txtFilterValue.Text, comparison) >= 0);
}
```

Comment: I finished setting it up as a query when you updated it. Thank you very much. You deserve those points!